# Something strange happen with python multiprocess

Tags: python

I've just tested python multiprocessing for reading file or a global variable, but there is something strange happen.

for expample:

```
import multiprocessing

a = 0

def test(lock, name):    
    global a
    with lock:        
        for i in range(10):
            a = a + 1
        print "in process %d : %d" % (name, a)

def main():    
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()            

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(lock, 1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(lock, 2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print "in main process : %d" % a

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The program read a global variable, but the output is:

```
in process 1 : 10
in process 2 : 10
in main process : 0
```

It seems that the sub-process cannot get and edit the global variable properly. Also, if I change the program to read the file, each sub-process will read the file completely, ignoring the lock.

So how does these happen? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: I believe that you'll need to manage the global state using a `multiprocessing.Manager`

Comment: You might use multithreading instead of multiprocessing for concurrent execution. All threads are part of a single process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables are not shared between processes. When you create and start a new `Process()`, that process runs inside a separate "cloned" copy of the current Python interpreter. Updating the variable from within a `Process()` will only update the variable locally to the particular process it is updated in.

To share data between Python processes, we need a [`multiprocessing.Pipe()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe), a [`multiprocessing.Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), a [`multiprocessing.Value()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value), a [`multiprocessing.Array()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) or one of the other multiprocessing-safe containers.

Here's an example based on your code:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(lock, counter, name):
    with lock:        
        for i in range(10):
            counter.value += 1

        print "In process {}: {}".format(name, counter.value)

def main():
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()    
    counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)         

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(lock, counter, 1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(lock, counter, 2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print "In main process: {}".format(counter.value)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

This gives me:

```
In process 1: 10
In process 2: 20
In main process: 20
```

Now, if you really want to use a global variable, you can use a [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager), but I think the first method is preferable, and this is a "heavier" solution. Here's an example:

```
import multiprocessing

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
counter = manager.Value('i', 0);

def worker(lock, name):
    global counter

    with lock:        
        for i in range(10):
            counter.value += 1

        print "In process {}: {}".format(name, counter.value)

def main():
    global counter

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()       

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(lock, 1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(lock, 2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print "In main process: {}".format(counter.value)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```